# Taking up a different time zone while building a maven project

Tags: java, maven, timezone, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven project where it depends on the different Timezone, 
Whenever I run a **mvn install**, I need to change my desktop time(IND) to US time zone(UTC-06:00).

Is there any way in the maven, while building a maven project it automatically 
picks up US time zone(UTC-06:00) ?

or any other way which we can solve this

I am using IntelliJ

Comment: What is the purpose of this? `-Duser.timezone=America/Chicago` will always work.

Comment: @Michael-O How to run  this command ?   , mvn clean install -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago ?

Comment: @Michael-O  i tried **mvn install -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago** and **mvn install -Duser.timezone='America/Chicago'** both did not work

Comment: You still did not tell why you are doing this.